# jqGrid doesn't overflow correctly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having an annoying problem with jqGrid: Instead of scrolling the lines, it just keeps adding them one bellow the other and doesn't stop at a certain height. What am I doing wrong? :S

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="libraries/jquery/custom-theme/jquery-ui.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="libraries/jquery/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css?" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/jquery/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="libraries/jquery/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid(
            {
                datatype: "local", 
                height: 350, 
                colNames:['Inv No','Date'], 
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
                    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"}
                ],
            multiselect: true,
            pager: '#pager5',
            caption: "Manipulating Array Data" }).navGrid("#pager5",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

    var mydata = [
                  {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01"},
                ...              
                  {id:"39",invdate:"2007-09-01"} 
                 ]; 
    for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++) jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="list4"></table>
<div id="pager5"></div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML file has no `<html>` element, no `DOCTYPE` before `<html>` and has unclear encoding (should be utf-8 and defined with `<meta>`, see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid as an example). You should also remove '?' after "ui.jqgrid.css" and change `<=` to `<` in the loop.

On http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Overflow.htm you can see the same file in a little modified form which works.